# How to unroot android device?

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-debug, adb

I have done root for android devices. I want to restore my android device to unroot state.
Is it possible to unroot android device using adb command or any other way?

Comment: use tis link http://www.technobuffalo.com/videos/how-to-unroot-return-your-android-phone/

Comment: This question belongs android only, its not general hardware and software

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now let’s see how to unroot your device (easy method):

```
1)  First download ES File Explorer from Google Play and don’t move to SD card.
2)  After that launch application and click on the slash button.
3)  Now tap the phone menu button to reveal new options and Root Explore setting it to ON.
4)  Next, allow Superuser to grant root privileges to the app.
5)  Navigate to System folder, then “bin” folder, then find “su” file.
6)  Select SU by pressing continuously on it and then delete.
7)  Navigate into xbin folder, in the System folder and delete the “su” file.
8)  In the app folder from System folder delete the Superuser.apk file.
9)  Reboot your device. Your device is now unrooted.
```